# Log user into Kentico Admin site based on HttpHeader value from Siteminder

Tags: kentico, siteminder

My company has just obtained Kentico for some new applications. These applications will be going into production in about 2 weeks, so we are still fairly new with this. What we have are three ASP.NET MVC applications/sites that format and present content that is stored in Kentico. Additionally, we have specific users who will log into the Kentico9/Admin site to manage the content displayed by the MVC apps.

From a corporate standpoint, we also have Siteminder SSO enabled. When a user navigates to our Kentico9/Admin site, they are first authenticated by our corporate Siteminder SSO form using their corporate user id. When they are successfully authenticated, Siteminder redirects the user to the Kentico9/Admin site they originally requested and the user is presented with the standard Kentico login form. If the user has already logged in through Siteminder during another session, they only get presented with the Kentico login form. Otherwise, if this is their first time logging in, the user is required to login twice (once through Siteminder and again through Kentico).

What I want to do is bypass the standard Kentico login form and use the Siteminder information to Authorize the user to log them into the Kentico admin site. Siteminder adds the username and some other information to the HTTP request headers. Using C#, I can retrieve their corporate user id using the following: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("SM_USERID")`.

So, in a nutshell, I want to override Kentico's standard login form and write some code that will get the user id from the HTTP request header and authorize the user by looking up their userid in Kentico. If the user id is not found or is not active, present the user with the standard Kentico login form. Otherwise, if the user is a valid and active user, pull their user record and allow them to access Kentico.

I have found some tidbits of information and given enough time, I may be able to figure something out, but I am hoping someone has done something similar and can speed up my process. Any ideas on what I can do? I will also entertain anything that might have tighter integration with Siteminder, although it doesn't seem Kentico can handle Siteminder out of the box, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be able to create a custom webpart which you will place on a page and simply have Siteminder redirect the user to the page with that webpart on it and look for those header values on page load.  If it finds them, perform your actions within Kentico to look that user up and authenticate them in Kentico as needed.  If there are no header values or it can't find the Kentico info, simply send them to the regular login page.

You could also create a global event handler but that would require someone to click a button or such on your site after they have entered credentials.